# conic sections, ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

A particle is travelling clockwise on the elliptical orbit given by
$$\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{100} + \frac{y^2}{25} = 1$$
The particle
leaves the orbit at the point $(-8, 3)$ and travels in a straight line tangent to the ellipse.
At which point will the particle cross the $y$-axis?

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried to do. What are your thoughts on the problem? Questions will be closed if you don't make an effort.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

From Article $262$ of [this](http://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone), the equation of the tangent at $P(h,k)$ of $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\text{   is      }\frac{x\cdot h}{a^2}+\frac{y\cdot k}{b^2}=1$$

So, the equation of the tangent here will be $$\frac{x\cdot (-8)}{100}+\frac{y\cdot 3}{25}=1$$

Now to cross the $y$ axis, $x=0$

Comment: ok so the particle crosses y at point zero?

Comment: cos if i make x=0, th eanswer i get is 25/3. is that the right thing? this question is so frustrating

Comment: Just solve for $y$ to get the intercept $\frac{25}{3}$.

Comment: ok... im so grateful

Comment: but there is  more,

Comment: @precious, "there is more" means?

Comment: Find the equations for
(a) the tangent lines, and
(b) the normal lines,
to the hyperbola
y2/4 - x^2\2= 1 when x = 4:

Comment: @precious, please ask different Question

Comment: wow, this is great, but the second question has nothing to do with the first. its on hyperbola while the first is on ellipse. the question says: Find the equations for
(a) the tangent lines, and
(b) the normal lines, to the hyperbola y^2/4 - x^2/2= 1 when x=4:

Answer (score 2):

We have $x^2/100+y^2/25=1$ so if we set $F(x,y)=x^2/100+y^2/25-1=0$ then $$y'=m_{\text{tangant} }=\frac{-F_x}{F_y}=\frac{-x}{4y}$$ and so $$m_{(-8,3)}=\frac{8}{12}$$ and the equation of the tangent line as @lab noted is $$y=\frac{8}{12}(x+8)+3$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like to work with homogeneous coordinates.

The ellipse is represented by

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{100} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{25} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

the 3×3 matrix such that

$$ \left. \begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{100} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{25} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =0 \right\} \frac{x^2}{100} + \frac{y^2}{25} -1 =0 $$

The tangent point is $P=(-8,3,1)$ (you verify tangency by $P\cdot C P=0$)

The tangent line is $L=C P = (-\frac{2}{25}, \frac{3}{25}, -1)$ with equation

$$ \left. (x,y,1) (-\frac{2}{25}, \frac{3}{25}, -1)=0 \right\} -2x+3y-25=0 $$

You can work out the rest.